# Всегда рендерить шаблоны по умолчанию

Tags: шаблоны, ruby, ruby-on-rails

В Rails 4 почему-то стандартно не рендерятся layouts-шаблоны из папки `app/views/layouts.`
Так, например, шаблон `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` не рендерится. Спасает лишь параметр `render layout:"application"` в экшенах контроллера..это ужасно неудобно. Можно ли как-то указать Rails, что НУЖНО рендерить шаблоны по умолчанию ВСЕГДА ?

**Спасибо**

**UPD:**

**1) Создал я новый проект и контроллер "hello"**
**2) Routing:**

```
root "hello#index"

  resources :hello do
    get :pops, on: :collection
  end
```

**3) Экшны контроллера:**

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController

def index
    render text: "Works"
  end

  def show
    render text: "Show"
  end

  def pops
    #render text: "Pops", layout: "application"  // работает
    render text: "Pops"  // не работает подгрузка layouts
  end

end
```

**4) app/views/layouts/application.html.erb :**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ror</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**5) при переходе** на URL "hello/pops" - шаблон не подгружен.

Comment: Мне кажется вы чего-то не договариваете. Совершенно случайно у вас в application_controller.rb нету что то типа layout false ? Ну или в самом контроллере?

Comment: Чад, думаю, я не совсем понял вопрос. Layout просто не рендерится при стандартно сгенерированном проекте через Rails консоль.

Comment: app/views/layout**s**/application.html.erb ?

Comment: Я только что сделал rails new proj, создал тестовый контроллер Hello с action'ом index. Запустил localhost:3000/hello/index. И чётко вижу, что application.html.erb рендерится, как и всегда. Можете выложить свой проект в zip-формате куда-нибудь на файлообменник, чтобы мы все глянули?

Comment: @Vetal4eg, я просто допустил опечатку. 

@Stanislaw Pankevich, вы тестировали на Rails 4, в UNIX-окружении ?

Ответ обновил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае и не должно рендриться c лайоутом т.к. вы указываете команду `render text: "..."`

Мне кажется, Вам надо создать вьюхи для акшенов контроллера, и не указывать render напрямую.

...

```
 touch app/views/hello/show.html.erb
```

...

```
def show

end
```

Как написано [здесь](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

> By default, if you use the :text
> option, the text is rendered without
> using the current layout. If you want
> Rails to put the text into the current
> layout, you need to add the layout:
> true option.

Comment: А, вот оно, в чем дело. Значит, при использовании `render text:` текущий layout не используется. Что ж, спасибо - я этого не знал.

Comment: Ну, собственно, логично. render text надо использовать для ajax например, но если хочется что то более сложное, это плохая идея перетягивать функционал view в контроллер.

Comment: @Чад, пока что это тестовое приложение. Конструкции `render text:` использовались, как заглушки. А так, конечно, перетягивание "отображения" в "контроллер" - не есть MVC.

Answer (score -2):

а твои партиалы начинаются на "_" ???
так то должны работать
<%= render "layouts/pratial" %>